# Alternate way of saying "The mass of the mass"?

Tags: writing, synonyms

I performed an experiment in which a mass was hung from a spring. I want to refer to the mass of the mass hung from said spring, but that leads to quite a few awkward sentences. I cannot refer to the mass as a weight, since masses and weights are two different things. Is there some alternate way of saying "The mass of the mass"?

Comment: Just call it something other than "the mass," such as "the mass of the object"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually simply avoided

> The mass of the mass is 10 kg.

can be

> The mass is 10 kg.

It's a contextual problem.  They used to refer to a computer case and it's insides as a CPU which was confusing if you wanted to mention the CPU chip in the same context.  In any one context it's best if X means only one thing.

Answer (score 0):

The mass of the suspended "object."  The problem here is of course that mass means something very specific in physics.  For example, in common language usage, I might say "there is a mass of vomit on the bathroom floor."  In that usage, I'm not particularly interested in knowing precisely what it's mass is.

Comment: Hmm... I suppose I could use that, but in a sense I'm giving up precision of language when using "object" instead of "mass".

Comment: I do "get" the problem...your mass and spring are intended to be physical-world representations of components of a math equation...so you like to use unit terms that directly translate.